# show total amount donated stripe

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment

I would like to use Paypal, Stripe, or some other similar service to accept donations and keep track of the total amount donated so I can display it on my site. I have not found a way to do this with Paypal or Stripe unless I keep track of it myself and update every time a donation is made. Any other possibilities? If I do end up keeping track of the total amount, any recommendations for doing that with a static site hosted on vercel? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to Paypal or any other services, but the easiest way for Stripe will be to keep track of it yourself, as there's no API you can use to retrieve totals like that.  It's likely also the easiest way no matter which service you're using.